# How to iterate Flux and mix with Mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I have a use case when I should send email to the users.
First I create email body.

```
Mono<String> emailBody = ...cache();
```

And then I select users and send the email to them:

```
Flux.fromIterable(userRepository.findAllByRole(Role.USER))
            .map(User::getEmail)
            .doOnNext(email -> sendEmail(email, emailBody.block(), massSendingSubject))
            .subscribe();
```

What I don't like

1. Without cache() method emailBody Mono calculates in each iteration step.
2. To get emailBody value I use emailBody.block() but maybe there's a reactive way and not call block method inside Flux flow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several issues in this code sample.
I'll assume that this is a reactive web application.

First, it's not clear how you are creating the email body; are you fetching things from a database or a remote service? If it is mostly CPU bound (and not I/O), then you don't need to wrap that into a reactive type. Now if it should be wrapper in a `Publisher` and the email content is the same for all users, using the `cache` operator is not a bad choice.

Also, `Flux.fromIterable(userRepository.findAllByRole(Role.USER))` suggest that you're calling a blocking repository from a reactive context.

You should **never** do heavy I/O operations in a `doOn***` operator. Those are made for logging or light side-effects operations. The fact that you need to `.block()` on it is another clue that you'll block your whole reactive pipeline.

Last one: you should not call `subscribe` anywhere in a web application. If this is bound to an HTTP request, you're basically triggering the reactive pipeline with no guarantee about resources or completion. Calling `subscribe` triggers the pipeline but does not wait until it's complete (this method returns a `Disposable`).

A more "typical" sample of that would look like:

```
Flux<User> users = userRepository.findAllByRole(Role.USER);
String emailBody = emailContentGenerator.createEmail();


// sendEmail() should return Mono<Void> to signal when the send operation is done
Mono<Void> sendEmailsOperation = users
     .flatMap(user -> sendEmail(user.getEmail(), emailBody, subject))
     .then();

// something else should subscribe to that reactive type,
// you could plug that as a return value of a Controller for example
```

If you're somehow stuck with blocking components (the `sendEmail` one, for example), you should schedule those blocking operations on a specific scheduler to avoid blocking your whole reactive pipeline. For that, look at the [Schedulers section on the reactor reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's very useful to understand doOn***. Email body is generated by fetching new items from DB and make some sort/group operation so it's Mono<String>. How would you modify sendEmailsOperation in this case?

Comment: sendEmail should probably take a Mono<String> or better, a Flux<DataBuffer> as an argument in that case.

Comment: sendEmail - 3d party API which expects Java types.  Also you can not just call Mono inside Flux like user.map(u-> sendEmail(emailBodyMono)) because someone should start emailBodyMono flow. I do it by calling block() method.

Comment: if you're calling blocking I/O APIs all around, then there's little benefit in using WebFlux. In the end, most of your code will need to be scheduled on special schedulers.

Comment: I understand it but we have much legacy Java blocking libraries. And I'm trying to mix reactive code with old as it's better then use old code everywhere.